# Obtain the list of open ports, windows firewall

Tags: arrays, vb.net, windows-firewall

I am trying to develop a code that manages the firewall ports using vb.net. The first part is to list all ports enabled. so I am trying this code:

```
Function portsList()
    Dim ports As INetFwOpenPorts
    Dim port As INetFwOpenPort
    Dim myPorts() As INetFwOpenPorts

    Dim NetFwMgrType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", False)
    Dim mgr As INetFwMgr = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType), INetFwMgr)
    ports = DirectCast(mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts, INetFwOpenPorts)
    Dim enumerate As System.Collections.IEnumerator = ports.GetEnumerator()

    Dim i As Integer
    While enumerate.MoveNext()
        port = DirectCast(enumerate.Current, INetFwOpenPort)
        myPorts(i) = port
        i += 1
    End While


    Dim portAsString() As String
    For j As Integer = 0 To i
        portAsString(j) = myPorts(j).ToString
    Next

    Return portAsString
End Function


Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim ports() As String = portsList()
    Dim n As String = ports.Length
    Dim newString As String = ""

    For h As Integer = 0 To n
        newString = ports(h) & vbNewLine
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Text = newString
End Sub
```

What I want to do is list all the ports in `Richtextbox1` after clicking `Button4`. The error that I am getting is:

> NullReferenceException was unHandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am new to Vb, how can I get over this?

Comment: Have you thought about scanning for open ports, instead of get a list from the firewall?

Comment: thanx @Sam I hadn't thought about it. Like i said, i want to block (close) some or all of these ports excerpt a few, how do i go about it in vb.net

Comment: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366423.aspx) and [here](http://www.johnkoerner.com/index.php?/archives/49-Creating-a-Firewall-Exception-in-VB.Net.html). By the way, scanning each port to see whether its open or closed can take a while (about 30 mins on a remote machine).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For port As Integer = 1 to maxPorts
    Dim host As String = "192.168.1.7"
    Dim hostadd As Net.IPAddress = Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList(0)
    Dim EPhost As New Net.IPEndPoint(hostadd, port)
    Dim s As New Net.Sockets.Socket(Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)

    Try
        s.Connect(EPhost)
    Catch
    End Try
    If s.Connected Then
        'Port opened
    Else
        'Port closed
    End If
Next
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17257/VB-Port-Scanner) you have the complete project.